Error message: Unable to render image tag in composer installation
In the backend, for extension "Open streetmap":
Unable to render image tag: File /public/_assets/82f949dc0aec213452344082e33eb19c/Icons/Extension.svg does not exist. (1509741914)
However, the file DOES exist. The image is shown when I do a request in another browser tab.
The same error in the front-end, for the bootstrap_package (it concerns "BootstrapPackage.svg").
Also, this image does exist.
My "composer" website is a copy of the website I developed with the legacy installation method.
The last works just fine.
Typo3: Version 12.4.15
I inspected the .htaccess, did some changes in the site-definition. Inspected, if the images are really there. I use Typo3 for more than 15 years now, but I cannot find a clue what can be the cause of the errors. Aside, this is my first installation with composer.
I hope someone recognizes this problem and can give me a hint.

Are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? Can you share the code involved, such that others could try to reproduce it?

The problem is in Typo3. Back-end and Front-end.
So, no, it is not a problem related to composer. The problem is related to the installation of typo3 with composer.
The http-requests for the involved images give a http-responsecode of 200; so nothing wrong there. But, Typo3 gives an unable to render image tag.

It is not a composer problem. The problem occurs within Typo3 (version 12.4.16). The http-requests for the images involved gives a response statuscode 200.
But Typo3 is not enabled to render the images.

This seems to be a problem with your baseURL and document root configuration.
Without much to go on I can only assume that your URL looks something like this: https://example.com/public and your document root is set to the parent directory containing the /public folder.
Because the document root is set to the parent folder, TYPO3 will generate the relative paths based on the parent directory, leading to paths like public/_assets/.... Combine that with the baseURL being set to https://example.com/public, the resulting URL to your assets looks like this: https://example.com/public/public/_assets/.
To fix this issue simply change your document root to the /public folder, i.e. var/www/httpdocs/public and adjust your baseURL to https://example.com.
